# How do I use external dependencies in IntelliJ typescript without Node.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, plotly, external-dependencies

I'm new to TypeScript, so sorry if this is basic.

I'm currently working on a small typescript webapp in IntelliJ IDEA 2020. I want it to run completely in browser, which I believe means I can't use Node for anything other than compiling into JavaScript. I also want to use some external dependencies, like JQuery and Plotly, which are available through NPM as well as by CDN and have `.d.ts` declaration files.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use those dependencies without IntelliJ complaining in the editor, TypeScript failing to compile, and/or my browser throwing an error when I try to run the compiled JavaScript. Right now I'm getting the former two: Plotly is red ("Cannot find name 'Plotly'.") and has a yellow underline ("Reference to a UMD global"). I've downloaded `plotly-latest` and `@types/plotly.js` in Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries, added `plotly.js` in Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Node.js and NPM, and directly included the `.d.ts` files in `tsconfig.json`. What am I missing?

Here's what my `tsconfig.json` looks like (I'm using AMD to let me import my source files into each other, but let me know if I'm doing that wrong or if there's something else I should put there):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2016", "DOM"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "module": "AMD",
    "outFile": "./build/build.js"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/*",
    "../../../.IntelliJIdea2019.3/config/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/jquery/misc.d.ts",
    "../../../.IntelliJIdea2019.3/config/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/tinyqueue/index.d.ts",
    "../../../.IntelliJIdea2019.3/config/javascript/extLibs/global-types/node_modules/@types/plotly.js/lib/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```